# C# : Thread Workload and Memory useage

Tags: c#, multithreading

the Windows Taskmanger is fine to check the CPU and memory useage of an application but in our programm we have different threads and we want to know how much of the total ammount is on each thread.

We would like to check this with an external programm and also from the application itself during runtime. It would be great if a thread could tell about his memory and cpu useage.

Answer (score 1):

Here's is the example:
You have threadA and ThreadB.
ThreadA creats an object X.
ThreadB uses this object.
So what do you want to see in thread's information? Who created the object or who is using it?
The only thing you can see is how much CPU time is using thread AFAIK
And all the same the only program that I know that shows MAX info on process is Process Explorer. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: That looks more like a comment to the question than an answer.

Comment: Ok, added some more info and possible solution.

Comment: No, it basicalyl says this is not possible. The ONLY memory allocatd TO A THREAD is the STACK. All the rest is shared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use performance monitor to see how much memory is allocated to a process, but you cannot see the same for single threads inside it.

However, you could create custom [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t90y2y1.aspx) to display any value you want to monitor from within your code.

Answer (score 0):

[SysInternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) has this feature, check [this Server fault thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/56980/getting-a-per-thread-cpu-statistics).

There is an open source project on CodeProject, the screenshot looks promising: [How to get CPU usage of processes and threads](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/processescpuusage.aspx), but the demo project seems to be crashing on Win7 (probably missing some privileges).

**[Edit]** If you want to write it yourself, you can P/Invoke [Thread32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686728%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [Thread32Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) functions to enumerate threads within a single process, and then use [QueryThreadCycleTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684943%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to query CPU time for each thread.

Answer (score -1):

Objects are shared between threads, threads do not own objects.

Memory for an object is allocated on the heap, which lives in the realm of the application. Any thread can access any of this memory at any time during the lifetime of the application.

There is no way to determine which thread is or may be using any arbitrary blocks of memory.

Threads perform units of work. Unless you know which thread is going to be running which unit of work you will be able to get no reliable metrics out of CPU usage. If you do know which thread will be performing which tasks, then [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) by SysInternals has this metric.

Comment: Could you clarify this? I am not sure I understand it.

Comment: This is not true. Memory usage can be tracked back to allocations by specific threads in C# and CPU usage is most certainly measurable per-thread.

Comment: @Polynomial not reliably nor consistently nor anything remotely useful. Consider static variables, the thread that created the objects may be removed from the thread pool and yet the memory still lives!! Remarkable. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: Well, if thread A has allocated a 1MB buffer, filled it with data, queued it to thread B and thread B has received it and is now working on it, who 'owns' the buffer?  A allocated it, but B is using it and will free it when it's done. This answer did not deserve a downvote.

Comment: @rich.okelly - The point is that for diagnostic purposes it is easy to track memory *allocations* made by a particular thread, which is a good first step in identifying memory leaks. I'm not going to remove the downvote, because I believe the answer you gave is incorrect. You also didn't fully answer the question, since the question asked about CPU usage as well as memory usage.

Comment: @MartinJames - You're correct in that there's no such thing as memory owned by a thread, but all memory is *allocated* by a thread. If you can track how much memory was allocated by a thread, and whether or not it has been freed at any point in time (which you can do) then you have a rough guide as to how "leaky" a thread is, or at least how much of an impact it is having on memory usage.

Comment: OP asked for CPU 'AND' memory useage, not 'OR'.  If one of those booleans is false, the whole expression is false.

Comment: @Martin James Do you really answer "yes" to your wife when she asks whether you want tea or coffee?

Comment: @Polynomial for diagnostic purposes you would use a profiler to see which objects are routed and where they are routed, not which thread happened to create them. Threads are not leaky, blocks of code are.

Comment: @MartinJames - You're being pedantic. By that logic if my local store is out of my favourite brand of coffee, I should leave the 30 other items I came in to purchase and go home empty-handed. Clearly it is more beneficial to give answers to both parts of the question, rather than half an answer to one part.

Comment: @rich.okelly - Sure, but if you've got 50 threads operating on the same code and only one is munching up half a gig of memory, the point at which the memory is allocated is a useless bit of information. Knowing *which* thread was doing the allocation is often important. Since you can tag each .NET thread with a name, you can trace this back to the parameters it was given or the data it is processing.

Comment: @Cicada - sometimes, but she then hits me with a teapot.

Comment: @Polynomial - I don't see that. If there are 50 threads in a pool, all executing the same code, then if one thread has an allocation problem, they all have it - any one could screw up and it would probably be a different one each time.  I can't see how a thread name helps much?

Comment: @MartinJames - Consider if the leak was subtle and dependant on the input data, e.g. if a loop's exit condition was faulty. If each thread is given different data (e.g. threads pull data from a queue) it will exhibit different behaviour. If only one data item is causing the fault, you can isolate the cause by setting each thread name to a unique ID that identifies the incoming data. You can then track allocations per thread and find the offending thread, then track it back to the source of the cause. Normal memory profiling will show you the offending *line*, but not the offending *state*.